# Preprocessing HTML files

Tags: template-engine, brunch

I'm evaluating brunch build system for my needs. I need to make simple HTML preprocessing. So basically I need to produce several files with common headers and footers:

file1.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="header">...</div>
  Page1
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

file2.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="header">...</div>
  Page2
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So either a simple include functionality or (preferrable) some kind of extends functionality. Ideally syntax should hide in comments so my IDE won't complain about non-HTML characters. I liked preprocess javascript library, but that's not necessary, of course.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything suited for that task in brunch. There's support for many HTML template engines, but they seem to generate JS functions. I need simple static HTML as a result, not JavaScript SPA.

Comment: Brunch does not currently have good handling for static html. Brunch (in its current form) is not likely to be a good fit for the requirements you've described.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain there's any built-in solution to this yet, but if I was to go in the direction of HTML templates / partials, I'd look into either "[after-brunch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/after-brunch)" and "[before-brunch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/before-brunch)" plugins on NPM.

I don't know what's your program-language of choice for FileSystem manipulation (read, merge, write, etc.), but in theory you could use something like "before-brunch" to execute a batch / shellscript / or command of somekind to collect your HTML partials together into your **file1.html**, **file2.html**, ... before Brunch compiles and copies it to the **public/** folder.

[image]

In case you're familiar with Haxe, here's a Gist that I shared a while ago. It's a post-process script to merge other files on specific lines of documents.

https://gist.github.com/bigp/90e38deeccc94145b033

Here's what an HTML document could look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DEMO</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
    <style id="css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        /* @MacroMerge: public/app.css */ //<--- Merges All CSS here..
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* @MacroMerge: public/vendor.js, public/app.js */ //<--- And all JS here..
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## EDIT:

Almost forgot, here's how the `brunch-config.coffee` script would use the Haxe script with the **after-brunch** plugin:

```
plugins:
    afterBrunch: [
        "haxe -cp . --macro MacroMerge.html('app/index.template.html','public/index.html')"
    ]
```

Come to think of it... nothing stops you from taking this example and specifying HTML partials (or any file extension really, ex: *.txt, *.xml) wherever you need them. Again, might only be useful to you if you're familiar with Haxe. If not, it's open-sourced & free to download (http://haxe.org/download/).